# Send FB Private Message to multiple people using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to send private message to multiple people using FB API, but I want it to received by the recipients individually not as group message, this is the code given by fb:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

this is how it looks like:

[image]

I found this code but it seems outdated or deprecated by fb

```
FB.ui({
           method: 'send',
           to: sendUIDs,
           name: "xxx",
           description:'xxx',
           link: 'http://www.mysite.com',
        });
```

what I want to achieve is make a fb message notif to my website users,
any idea guys how to achieve it? is it even possible?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only can do it with images. Send the picture to your self, click on the picture, on the bottom right click on forward. Facebook will show you a list of friends with boxes where you can choose the recipients you want to "Forward in separate messages"

P.S. You make want to take a screen picture of your text in order to "Forward [the message] in separate messages"

I hope it helps.